# Htaccess disable php files uploading except my IP

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, uploading

I am also fighting with hackers on my Joomla sites. I have problems especially with php files injection. One of my idea is disable uploading .php files globally on whole web and allow uploading .php files only from my IP. Is it chance disable upload using htaccess (only disable uploading .php files not disable .php execution) ?

At this moment i am able to turn off php function for example in image folders using `php_flag engine off`, but this does not solve my problem. Or it is possible to make it easily on server side settings ? Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Hi mira, this link will help you to protect execution from image folder http://www.itoctopus.com/quick-joomla-security-tip-disable-php-execution-in-the-images-folder

Comment: Hi, thanks, but is there any sollution for whole web ? Lets say I need protect all directories not only images folder.

Comment: You need Joomla itself to run, so you need some way to distinguish between "safe" and "unsafe" scripts. "Unsafe" ones would be the ones uploaded to your `image` folder, so if you prevent execution in there then it can't self-replicate to other "presumed safe" locations.